# Local cohomology groups and linearity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

I am reading local cohomology and am confused on a silly point. Let $U$ be an affine, non-singular variety and $Z \subset U$ a hypersurface section on $U$ (i.e., complete intersection in $U$ of codimension $1$). We know that we have an exact sequence, $$H^0(\mathcal{O}_U) \to H^0(U-Z,\mathcal{O}_U|_{U-Z}) \xrightarrow{\delta} H^1_Z(\mathcal{O}_U)$$

My question is: Is $\delta$ a $\mathcal{O}_U(U)$-linear morphism? If so, then it seems that $H^1_Z(\mathcal{O}_U) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_U(U)} \mathcal{O}_Z(Z)$ should be zero. Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please compute through an example before asking! What happens if $U = \text{Spec}(k[x])$ and $Z = V(x)$?

Later edit. The answer to your question is that if $A$ is a ring and $f \in A$ an element, and $M$ an $A$-module, then we can look at the sequence
$$
0 \to M[f^\infty] \to M \to M_f \to M_f/M \to 0 \to 0 \to \ldots
$$
This sequence will be isomorphic, as a sequence of $A$-modules, to the sequence
$$
0 \to H^0_Z(X, \mathcal{F}) \to H^0(X, \mathcal{F}) \to H^0(U, \mathcal{F}) \to
H^1_Z(X, \mathcal{F}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{F}) \to \ldots
$$
where $X = \text{Spec}(A)$, $Z = V(f)$, $U = X \setminus Z$, and $\mathcal{F}$ is the quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module associated to $M$. Since the functor $\otimes_A A/fA$ is right exact and since $M_f \otimes_A A/fA = 0$ we find that the tensor product you wrote down is zero.

In the above I am using cohomology with supports $H^i_Z$. This can be defined for an arbitrary closed subset $Z$ of a topological space $X$. This then gives me long exact sequences relating $H^i_Z(X, -)$, $H^i(X, -)$, $H^i(U, -)$. If $-$ is an abelian sheaf, then these are long exact sequences of abelian groups. If $-$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, then these are long exact sequences of $\Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$-modules. You can prove this by taking a resolution by injectives in the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules and using general theorems saying that such resolutions compute the right thing (i.e., the same as what you get for abelian sheaves). Or you can use the functoriality of the construction (because multiplying by an global section of the structure sheaf commutes with everything in sight).

Comment: Thank you. I am not very familiar with computations in local cohomology. Could you please suggest a hint/reference how to compute $H^1_Z(\mathcal{O}_U)$ in this case. In particular, I do not know of any particular injective resolution of $\mathcal{O}_U$, which could help in the computation.

Comment: @user45397 In this case it's easy to figure out $H^0(U, \mathcal O_U)$ and $H^0(U-Z, \mathcal O_U)$, without knowing anything about local cohomology. So you just need to find the map between them. An injective resolution is not needed.

Comment: @Sawin: I am sorry, I still do not understand how to show that $\delta$ is not $\mathcal{O}_U(U)$-linear. Could you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: @Kohl: I am confused. The previous question is not a new question but rather a follow up of the answer above. There is nothing new in it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user45397 Stefan and Will might not have seen your comments because you need to write 'at StefanKohl' or 'at WillSawin' for messages to appear in their inboxes. Anyway, I think Stefan was addressing the answerer Vlad who ends his answer with a 'question'. It's a Socratic question, obviously. I would encourage Vlad to expand this into more of a detailed explanation, lest certain reviewers in the review queue have his answer deleted via Community vote.

Comment: @WillSawin I guess the counterexample above is to disprove that "$\delta$ is $\mathcal{O}_U(U)$-linear". Could you please elaborate on how I can show this.

Comment: @Vlad: Thank you very much. So, the answer to both the questions is yes, am I right? I thought you were giving a counterexample earlier, so I was confused.

Comment: @user45397 My confusion about your question was: how can you know about cohomology with supports but not know that the boundary map is linear? But I did not express myself very well. Apologies.

Comment: @Vlad: Thank you very much for the very detailed and helpful answer. I could not find any reference where they mention this linearlity property. In all literatures, they work with the category of abelian groups as soon as they apply the cohomology functor/right derived functor and not in the category of modules. I thought the boundary map must be linear but was puzzled by the tensor product conclusion, since I was not expecting it. Thanks once again.

Comment: So, "Vlad Dezamagit" now?  Does this refer to Vlad during his imprisonment by Corvinus?